# Charge of a composite fermion

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, field-theory, fermions

Suppose a fermion being a composite of two other fermions
$$\psi=\varphi\cos\theta+\chi\sin\theta.$$
If $\varphi$ and $\chi$ satisfy the Dirac equations
$$i\!\!\not\!\partial\varphi=e_{\varphi}\!\!\not\!\!A\varphi \\
i\!\!\not\!\partial\chi=e_{\chi}\!\!\not\!\!A\chi,$$
then $\psi$ should satisfy some Dirac equation
$$i\!\!\not\!\partial\psi=e_\psi\!\!\not\!\!A\psi.$$
However, summing the first two equations, I get
$$i\!\!\not\!\partial\psi=\,\not\!\!A[e_{\varphi}\cos(\theta)\,\varphi+e_{\chi} \sin(\theta)\,\chi].$$
How do I get the charge $e_{\psi}$?

Comment: An example in nature?

Comment: @annav for example, generation mixing with CKM-matrix, the only difference is that charges are the same

Comment: that is a mathematical example. by nature I mean an existing particle,  atom or molecule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\psi = \varphi \cos \theta+\chi \sin \theta$ does not describe a "composite" field of the two (massless) fermions $\varphi$ and $\chi$ but a "mixture". However, fields with different charges $e_\varphi \ne e_\chi$ cannot be mixed (superselection rule). Only fields of the same charge sector can be mixed, which is usually done to identify the mass eigenfields.